# Models for Probability Density Functions with unknown parameters and given mean and variance

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-analysis

The PDF $f(x)$ of a non-negative random variable $x$ has the structure $$f(x)=\exp (a-bx-cx^{2})$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are any model parameters. It is assumed that $c\ge 0$ so that $f(x)$ does not diverge for large $x$.  Also given that the mean value $$\mu=\frac{e^{a}-b}{2c}$$ and $$\sigma^{2}=\frac{1-b\mu}{2c}-\mu^2$$

Develop a numerical scheme for finding the parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$ so that the PDF agrees with any given mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: One should not use the same symbol for both a random variable and the argument to its density function.  If one calls the former $X$ and the latter $x$, then one can understand things like $\Pr(X>x)$ and $f_X(3)$. $\qquad$

Comment: okay thank you for the notice. But do you have any idea about the question?

Comment: "Developed a numerical scheme" suggests that what is to be done is neither algebra nor evalutation of integrals, but rather numerical solution for $a,b,c$ of the system of two displayed equations when given $\mu\ge0$ and $\sigma^2\ge0$. $\qquad$

Comment: so basically I just need to try to write my $a$,$b$ and $c$ in forms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: Apparently so.  (BTW, a typo: "evaluation".) $\qquad$